# How to submit a form using ActionLink

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I've got to buttons - one sub submission and one for cancellation. The former is the usual *input* control in side the form.

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "List", "Home", null, new { @class = "cancel" })
<input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

The above works as supposed to. However, I got unhappy with how the code looks, so I've attempted to execute both events using *ActionLink*, like so.

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "List", "Home", null, new { @class = "cancel" })
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Save", "Home", null, new { 
  @class = "submit", 
  onclick = "javascript:document.forms[0].submit()" })
```

When I execute it, I get a hit on the controller but the model being passed back is empty (i.e. all fields are default valued). I'm guessing that the action link sends me to *Save* from outside the form's context but I don't know how to make it not do so.

At the very least, I'd expect the page to send **two** calls. One based on the dummy model through the *ActionLink*'s *href* and the second invoked by the JS being executed.

How do I make it work? Is there a better approach? Mainly, I don't want to style the *input* control. I prefer to style the links generated by *Html.ActionLink*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.ActionLink` produces a an anchor tag and clicking on which usually produces a GET request. Normally, you cannot submit your form data using that.

What you can do is, when user clicks on your link, using javascript-jQuery, serialize the form using jQuery `serialize()` method and send it using ajax.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <label>Name </label> @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.FirstName)

   @Html.ActionLink("Save","Save","Home",null,new { class="sbmt" })

}
```

This will generate an anchor tag with a css class sbmt inside your form tag and in your javascript, listen to the `click` event on the anchor tag with this css class.

```
$(function(){

  $("a.sbmt").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();  // prevent default form submit behaviour since we are doing ajax
    var _f=$(this).closest("form");

    $.post(_f.attr("action"),_f.serialize(),function(res){
       //do something with the response coming back from your Save action method.
       if(res.status==="success")
       {
           alert("Saved");
          // If you want to reload the page, you can do this
           window.location.href=window.location.href; 

       }
    });

  });

});
```

Since we are making an ajax request, It is a good idea to return a json response from the action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(YourViewModel model)
{
  // Save 
  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
  {
     return Json(new {status="success"});           
  }
  return RedirectToAction("Index"); //if not an ajax request, do the redirect
}
```

Comment: Can I use plain JS to invoke a click on the input button? (And then hide the button from the view so they won't be any wiser? My controller used for saving doesn't return a view - it just redirects to the same page as cancel button does (after a small trip to DB saving the update, of course). Or is jQ the only (reasonable) way?

Comment: You can do it without jQuery library. But you have to write some javascript code to send data. IF you have one or two fields you are sending, you don't need the serialize method. you can append it in querystring and send.  To reload the page, See my edit in the answer. jQuery is a very useful library to help you in a lot of stuff and the default MVC project template includes that. Why not use it :)

Comment: In the first example, you wrote *new { class="sbmt" }*. I always use @ sign as in *@class* because I thought that reserved wordsin C# must be @-ified under Razor. Is the above a typo or doesn't it matter?